# Contenteditable div text get's added into span element and not outside

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've a problem with my contenteditable div. When I click the button, a span get's inserted into my div. When I start now typing, the text goes inside the span and not outside of it:

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  let input = $("#input");

  input.on("input", function() {
    console.log($(this).html().length);
    
    // Contenteditable adds a <br> when empty.
    // Solutions on SO appear not to work
    if (!$(this).text()) {
      input.html('');
    }
  });

  $("button").click(function() {
    input.html(input.html() + `<span class="emoji"></span>`);
    input.trigger('input');
  });
});
```

```css
[contenteditable=true] {
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
  padding: 8px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

[contenteditable=true]:empty:before {
  content: attr(placeholder);
  display: block;
  color: #aaaaaa;
}

.emoji {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="input" placeholder="Schreib eine Nachricht..." contenteditable="true" spellcheck="true"></div>
<button>Add element to contenteditable div</button>
```

Thats a really strange thing. And also when I add an emoji, delete the content and type something in, a `<font>` element get's created with the style of an emoji. Does anyone know how I can fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add `contenteditable="false"` on your `span`.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  let input = $("#input");

  input.on("input", function() {
    console.log($(this).html().length);
    
    // Contenteditable adds a <br> when empty.
    // Solutions on SO appear not to work
    if (!$(this).text()) {
      input.html('');
    }
  });

  $("button").click(function() {
    input.html(input.html() + `<span class="emoji" contenteditable="false"></span>`);
    input.trigger('input');
  });
});
```

```css
[contenteditable=true] {
  border: 1px solid #aaaaaa;
  padding: 8px;
  border-radius: 12px;
  margin-bottom: 20px;
}

[contenteditable=true]:empty:before {
  content: attr(placeholder);
  display: block;
  color: #aaaaaa;
}

.emoji {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="input" placeholder="Schreib eine Nachricht..." contenteditable="true" spellcheck="true"></div>
<button>Add element to contenteditable div</button>
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use img tag for inserting emojis, I strongly advise to take a look at [telegram web](https://web.telegram.org), or other web based chat application to see what you should do about handling emojis.

Comment: Using img with emojis as a text and not as an image causes the img to be invalid.

Comment: @Mr.Jo you shouldn't use text, take a look at https://github.com/twitter/twemoji

Comment: As I'm developing in PHP, a JS library wouldn't work.